# Access VBA Not Printing Properly

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I have a table...

A1  B1

A2  B2

A3  B3

A4  B4

A5  B5

.   .

.   .

.   .

and it randomly prints like...

BLANK  BLANK

BLANK  BLANK

BLANK  BLANK

BLANK  BLANK

A4     B4

A5     B5

.      .

.      .

.      .

Where blank is what I can see as actually being blank. I cannot find any character within the record. Code below. It prints the same number of records. I am using a form and and calling in the table name as Table.

```
Option Compare Database

Sub Concatenate(Table As String)
' Set the database
  'Dim dbsCyme_Model_Update As DAO.Database
 'Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
 Set dbsCyme_Model_Update = CurrentDb
 Dim Field As String

'Count records and fields
RecordCount = CurrentDb.TableDefs(Table).RecordCount
fieldCount = CurrentDb.TableDefs(Table).Fields.Count
Debug.Print "00000"; RecordCount; fieldCount;
RecordCounter = 0
ReDim fieldArray(0) As String
ReDim recordArray(0) As String
ReDim fieldArray(fieldCount - 1) As String
ReDim recordArray(RecordCount - 1) As String
Set rst = dbsCyme_Model_Update.OpenRecordset(Table)
rst.MoveFirst
Do Until rst.EOF
    'Field data
    fieldCounter = 1
    While fieldCounter < fieldCount
        'Set Recordset

        Field = "Field" & fieldCounter
        'rstGENERAL
        fieldString = rst.Fields(Field)
        fieldArray(fieldCounter - 1) = fieldString
        fieldCounter = fieldCounter + 1
    Wend
    printCounter = 0
    For Each element In fieldArray
        If Not fieldArray(printCounter) = "N/A" Then
           holder = recordArray(RecordCounter)
            If fieldArray(printCounter + 1) = "N/A" Then
                recordArray(RecordCounter) = holder + fieldArray(printCounter)
            Else
                recordArray(RecordCounter) = holder + fieldArray(printCounter) + ","
            End If
                printCounter = printCounter + 1
        End If

    Next element
    RecordCounter = RecordCounter + 1
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Dim temp As String

'Print to the CymeImportFile
Dim bob As String
bob = 0
Set rst = dbsCyme_Model_Update.OpenRecordset("CymeImportFile")

'rst.MoveFirst
RecordCounter = 0
    If rst.BOF Then
        rst.AddNew
        rst.Update
        rst.MovePrevious
    Else
        rst.MoveLast
        rst.MoveNext
        rst.AddNew
        rst.Update
        rst.MovePrevious
    End If

For Each element In recordArray
    rst.Edit
    temp = recordArray(RecordCounter)
    rst!Field1 = temp
    rst.Update
    rst.MoveNext
    If rst.EOF Then
        rst.AddNew
        rst.Update
        rst.MovePrevious
    End If
    RecordCounter = RecordCounter + 1
Next element
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
ReDim fieldArray(0) As String
ReDim recordArray(0) As String
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. All those different adds and updates confused everything. I simplified it down to this.

**New code:**

```
'Print to the CymeImportFile
Dim bob As String
bob = 0
Set rst = dbsCyme_Model_Update.OpenRecordset("CymeImportFile")
RecordCounter = 0
rst.MoveLast
rst.AddNew
For Each element In recordArray

'rst.Edit

rst.AddNew
temp = recordArray(RecordCounter)
rst!Field1 = temp
rst.Update
RecordCounter = RecordCounter + 1
Next element
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
ReDim fieldArray(0) As String
ReDim  recordArray(0) As String

Debug.Print Table
End Sub
```